# wireshark custom lua dissector display metaData column

Tags: lua, metadata, decode, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

For a wireshark custom lua dissector, id like to be able to display the "append_text" metaData in the wireshark column view.
Makes it easier for other folk to see what's going on

i.e. in this case id like the msgType column to show "00 (heartbeat)" instead of simply "0"

Or open to any other way to expose the "Heartbeat" metaData in the column view
(effectively expose append_text from my custom dissector)

Many Thanks

[image: custom lua dissector]

Answer (score 3):

First, there's no need to use `append_text`.  Assuming **msgType** is a 1-byte unsigned field, declare it this way:

```
local msg_type_vals = {
    [0] = "Heartbeat",
    [1] = "Foo",
    [2] = "Bar",
    ...
}

msgType = ProtoField.uint8("aquis.msgType", "Message Type", base.DEC, msg_type_vals)

...

tree:add(msgType, tvbuf(offset, 1))
```

Now if you apply this field as a column, you'll see the text, **Heartbeat** instead of **0**.

If you want to display both the numeric value and the text value, you can do this as follows:

1. Add 2 columns of the same field.  Wireshark doesn't seem to allow you to *"Apply as column"* by right-clicking on the field if the field has already been added; however, you can still add it from *Edit -> Preferences -> Columns -> +*
2. Locate your personal preferences directory from Wireshark's *Help -> About Wireshark -> Folders -> Personal configuration*.
3. Quit Wireshark
4. From your editor of choice, open the **preferences** file in the personal configuration folder, or if you're using  a Profile other than the default profile, open the **preferences** file in the applicable profile instead.
5. Locate the line that specifies the column format by searching for `gui.column.format`.
6. You'll notice that both columns for your custom field will be of the form:

```
    "Message Type", "%Cus:aquis.msgType:0:R",
```

Change one of them to:

```
    "Message Type", "%Cus:aquis.msgType:0:U",
```

The meaning of `R` is to indicate that this is a *Resolved* field, which is the default, and the meaning of `U` is to indicate that this is an *Unresolved* field.  The former will give you **Heartbeat** while the latter will give you **0**.  Unfortunately, there is currently no way to change this from the Wireshark column preferences dialog itself, so it's necessary to manually edit the file to achieve this.

7. Save the file and restart Wireshark.  You should see both resolved and unresolved values now.